# Substituting a value for a reference

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I feel like this should have a simple answer. I have the following formula:

```
=query(DATA, "select * where A='Tues'")
```

I want it to reference the contents of a specific cell to use as a filter, for example A1, instead of manually inputting the filter (`'Tues'` for example) into the formula when I want to change it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try-

```
=QUERY(DATA,"select * where A='" & A1 & "'")
```

Answer (score 0):

or try:

```
=FILTER(DATA, DATA!A:A=A1)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.